# Get row.name after grouping with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm new with data.table but I've managed to reduce a computation in a dataset of 600K rows from thousands of seconds (using *ply loops) to 1.7sec. Basically I need the row with the lowest value in the column **class** in the groups of the same **group** and **start**. I'm using

```
DT[, list(class=min(class)), by=list(group, start)]
```

But to do that I created DT with only these 3 columns from a data.frame with more columns. So, to merge my results with the original data.frame I'm thinking of using the row.name, so I created DT with **row.name=TRUE** and this is an example of what I have:

```
   group   start     class     rn
 1:  A      4943         4      1
 2:  A      5030         0      2
 3:  A      5030         4      3
 4:  A      5030         2      4
 5:  A      5083         4      5
 6:  A      5083         3      6
 7:  B      5041         0      7
 8:  B      5041         1      8
 9:  B      5083         4      9
 ...
```

My desired result is only the **rn** corresponding to the minimium **class** value:

```
   group   start     class     rn
 1:  A      4943         4      1
 2:  A      5030         0      2
 3:  A      5083         3      6
 4:  B      5041         0      7
 5:  B      5083         4      9
 ...
```

But if I use:

```
DT[, list(class=min(class)), by=list(group, start, rn)]
```

or

```
DT[, list(class=min(class), rn), by=list(group, start)]
```

I get all the rows, not only the rows with **class** minimum.

**Extra question**

I'd be possible to get a count of the cases of each class type in the group using data.table sintax using my command?

```
   group   start     class     rn    class0    class1    class2    class3    class4
 1:  A      4943         4      1         0         0         0         0         1
 2:  A      5030         0      2         1         0         1         0         1
 3:  A      5083         3      6         0         0         0         1         1
 4:  B      5041         0      7         1         1         0         0         0
 5:  B      5083         4      9         0         0         0         0         1
 ...
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the "extra question". Could you explain a bit more as to how these values of 1 and 0 get filled in these columns and why class0 - class4?

Comment: Hi, I suppose it's a bit confusing because the class numbers correspond to factors in the original data.frame, I convert them to obtain only the minimum(or the first as in your method). What I try to do in the extra is to count how many there are from each class for each group. For example for group=="A" and start==5030 there are 1'zero', 1'two' and 1'four'

Comment: Okay, got it. Let me try to see if I can find a way.

Comment: I think `dt[, list(class=class[1], rn=rn[1], class0=length(class[class==0])), by=list(group, start)]` solved it! Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can do that for each class manually (or) you can check out edit 2 to do this directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, you're basically calling `min` on each group. This is not necessary. If you sort the column `class` as well (by setting the `key`), then you can use `mult="first"` feature to just pick the smallest element directly. That is,

```
setkey(dt, group, start, class)
dt[CJ(unique(group), unique(start)), mult="first", nomatch=0]
   group start class rn
1:     A  4943     4  1
2:     A  5030     0  2
3:     A  5083     3  6
4:     B  5041     0  7
5:     B  5083     4  9
```

---

Alternatively if you don't want to use `CJ` here, then you can do this:

```
setkey(dt, group, start, class)
dt[, list(class=class[1], rn=rn[1]), by=list(group, start)]
```

---

Edit 2:

Here's a complete answer:

```
dt.out <- dt[, c(list(class = class[1], rn=rn[1]), 
       {tt <- rep(0,5); tt[class+1] <- 1; as.list(tt)}), by=list(group, start)]
setnames(dt.out, 5:9, paste0("Class", 0:4))

   group start class rn Class0 Class1 Class2 Class3 Class4
1:     A  4943     4  1      0      0      0      0      1
2:     A  5030     0  2      1      0      1      0      1
3:     A  5083     3  6      0      0      0      1      1
4:     B  5041     0  7      1      1      0      0      0
5:     B  5083     4  9      0      0      0      0      1
```

Comment: Thanks! both methods worked just fine. I think I prefer the second one, since it's more clear for me how to add more columns.

Comment: as far as clarity goes, I like this version most - `dt[, .SD[which.min(class)], by = list(group, start)]` (and then use `.SDcols` to adjust what you want in `.SD`)

Comment: @eddi, I agree w.r.t. clarity. The problem is the calls to `min` *may* be costly if for example you've 1e7 rows with 1e5 groups.. Essentially you're calling that many `which.min`. From what I've tested, setting key and pulling out the first row always came out faster. And I've an aversion to `.SD` :) (again performance reasons). I try to avoid it amap. That's the reason for a cluttered answer.